# Was a star-crossed lover

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, wordplay

> This is the riddle of the star-crossed lover,
>   His insignia etched forever,
>   Whose name foretold unhappiness,
>   Proving that the ends justify the means,
>
> To the North: Round like an empennage orb,
>   To the East: Half delta, anyhow a pair I was,
>   To the South: A dual neb, I render hue two,
>   To the West: Wing metacarpi, white swan ulna nigh,
>
> I myself: Was a star-crossed lover,
>
> Who/what am I?

Comment: geography tag or not?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are ...

> ... **Sadr** or Gamma Cygni, a star in the constellation of Cygnus.

How so?

> The fourth line says that "the ends justify the means", and if we take the "ends" of the words in the second stanza, we get:
>
>      To the North:   **Deneb**       (Alpha Cygni)
>      To the East:    **Fawaris**     (Delta Cygni)
>      To the South:   **Albireo**     (Beta Cygni)
>      To the West:    **Gienah**      (Epsilon Cygni)
>
>  The Cygnus constellation looks a bit like a cross with these stars lying more or less in the given celestial directions. In the middle is **Sadr** or Gamma Cygni.
>
>  There are some more hints: Albireo is a dual star; Fawaris has "delta" in its phrase; Cygnus means "swan" and probably some that I have missed.
>
>  As for Sadr itself, "Hi**s** insigni**a** etche**d** foreve**r**" spells its name in the same fashion as the names of its neighbours; It has "sad" in its name, thereby foretelling unhappiness, and using the Phonetic alphabet to describe the R, we get "Sad Romeo", one of Shakespeare's star-crossed lovers. And, of course, Cygnus itself is a "star cross".

Comment: Nice job. Also, rot13(gur fnzr zrgubq ba gur gvgyr vgrys lvryqf 'fnqe' nf jryy...)

Comment: Rot13: Nqqvgvbany pyhrf (V qvqa'g rkcrpg nyy gb or sbhaq): "vafvtavn" fbhaqf yvxr "va Pltav"; rzcraantr = gnvy, Qraro vf gur gnvy bs gur fjna; Snjnevf vf bar unys bs Qrygn Pltav (n ovanel fgne); aro = ornx, Nyoverb vf gur urnq/ornx naq vf n ovanel fgne jvgu gjb qvfgvapg pbybef: tbyq naq oyhr ("eraqre uhr gjb"); Tvranu vf gur jvat (gur anzr npghnyyl zrnaf "jvat" va Nenovp); "jnf n fgne-pebffrq ybire" fcryyf bhg "fnqe" nf jryy.